# Ubuntu Server 23.10 Error

Tags: server

I'm running Ubuntu Server 23.10 to learn about server operation.

Hardware:
Dell Optiplex 790 MT
1TB SATA hard drive
16GB Memory (maximum the computer can have)

The hard drive passes all bios testing
The memory passes all bios testing

I ran smartctl with the following results

---

***smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.5.0-25-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, [www.smartmontools.org](http://www.smartmontools.org)
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Green
Device Model:     WDC WD10EZRX-00D8PB0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC4MNVAS898
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2b5a524b3
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Mar 17 19:05:54 2024 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
was completed without error.
Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
without error or no self-test has ever
been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:        (13980) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
Suspend Offline collection upon new
command.
Offline surface scan supported.
Self-test supported.
Conveyance Self-test supported.
Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
power-saving mode.
Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 144) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x7035) SCT Status supported.
SCT Feature Control supported.
SCT Data Table supported.
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       308
3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   179   170   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       4050
4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       4327
5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   024   024   000    Old_age   Always       -       55794
10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       4326
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       144
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   194   194   000    Old_age   Always       -       18990
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   118   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       29
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       10
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       8
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       47
SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error

## 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     55762         -

## 2  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     55762         -

## 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     55761         -

## 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     55761         -

## 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     54839         -

## 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     54293         -

## 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     50672         -

## 8  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%     49849         -

## 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     49845         -

#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     48956         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     48956         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     47508         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     47113         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     46313         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     44905         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     43584         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     43584         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     41946         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     40038         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     39492         -
#21  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      50%     38405         -
SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
1        0        0  Not_testing
2        0        0  Not_testing
3        0        0  Not_testing
4        0        0  Not_testing
5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.***

---

The error that appears on the monitor, not all the time, is:

---

***ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 actioin 0x6 frozen
ata1.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
ata1.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 14
res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
ata1.00: status. { DRDY }***

---

If I read the systemctl results, there's no hardware failures.
I can still access the files in the

/srv/samba/share

folders from Windows and Linux Mint.

The server has no failures/errors during boot and the error does not
cause the server to fail. It appears to be a nuisance error.

Anyone ever see this error and if so is there a fix for it?

Thanks for the support.